# How to merge lines from csv files in one single file, excluding the header rows

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a number of csv files that use the following format:

```
file_1.csv
line 1 -- header row
line 2 -- header row
line 3 -- data row

file_2.csv
line 1 -- header row
line 2 -- header row
line 3 -- data row
...
file_n.csv
line 1 -- header row
line 2 -- header row
line 3 -- data row
```

and would like to script something that puts them all in one single file having the 2 header lines copied only once, as follows:

```
fileMerged.csv
line 1 -- header row
line 2 -- header row
line 3 -- data row from file_1
line 4 -- data row from file_2
...
line n+2 -- data row from file_n
```

What is the best way to achieve this in a Linux server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR||FNR>2' file_*.csv > fileMerged.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=( file_*.csv ) # collect input filenames in an array

{
  head -n 2 "${files[0]}" # output the header lines (using the 1st file)
  tail -q -n +3 "${files[@]}" # append the data lines from all files, in sequence
}  > out.csv
```

---

**[lihao's elegant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40922632/45375) offers a simpler solution** that clearly satisfied the OP's requirements.

---

If you're interested in a ***variation* of the problem** where **lines should be copied *cyclically* from the input files**: the *respective* first lines from each input file, followed by the respective second lines, ...:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=( file_*.csv ) # collect input filenames in an array

{
  head -n 2 "${files[0]}" # output the header lines (using the 1st file)
  paste -d'\n' "${files[@]}" | tail -n +"$(( 1 + 2 * ${#files[@]} ))"
}  > out.csv
```